# Can I Publish or Create New Application while there are still applications that are suspended?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

i want to ask

can you publish or create a new application while there are still apps suspended in the PlayStore account?

Shouldn't you solve the problem of suspended applications before you can publish or create a new application?

What if I don't care about the problem of this suspended application, and immediately publish or create another application with the name, application name, package name, icon, new logo? will the new application be suspended too?

please tell me is it true that if 3 applications are suspended (multiple strike), will the playstore account that I use be suspended too?

so this the problem, my application has been suspend, and I have sent an appeal to google playstore developer.

they reply like this :

> "If your developer credentials are still in good standing with Google
>   Play and if your app allows for it, you can publish a new compliant
>   version of the app by following these steps:
>
> 1. Make the necessary changes to your app to address the issue described above, if possible.
> 2. Double check that your app complies with all other Developer Program Policies. Additional enforcement could occur if there are
>      further policy violations.
> 3. Sign in to your Play Console and upload a new app using a new package name and a new app name"

see point 3 (number 3), they told me to upload a new application, while the suspended application was not unsuspended, how can I submit application updates?

can I publish or create a new application while there are still apps suspended in my playstore account?

please help me, the google playstore team doesn't help at all, maybe I can use the answers from you to appeal

please help me sir, i need your help about this problem

thanks before

Comment: You should be asking that to Play customer support because they make policy not us..And policies are  revises  over time

Comment: thanks sir for reply, I have replied to the email, asking through chat, they did not help me at all, maybe you can help me sir about this problem. thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can publish app on store until you have 2 suspend application. on third suspension of any of your app your whole account will be banned.

There are no option to delete app, play store has access of unpublished apk, so if you are going to publish same app which is unpublished by you then there must be something new or improvement.

google will take more then 4 days to process update or live app if you have any unpublished app in your account.

Answer (score -1):

No, I have one suspended application in my play console account still i am able create and update existing application.

Better to resolve your suspension or you can unpublish/remove those app.
No worry, Enjoy :)

Comment: thanks sir for reply, how can i unpublish or remove while the application status is still suspended? I can't set "unplished" if my app status are suspended